# Objective C. Tracking down an unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, selector, unrecognized-selector

I have a fairly complex project that I am working on. I am getting an error related to an unrecognized selector. Usually I can track these problems down quickly, generally just using logic, else using NSLog or break points. I'm having trouble finding this one.

What is the methodical way to track down this problem?

Comment: By seeing the code with specs.... show us the code...

Comment: Do you have a symbolicated stack trace? The name of the unrecognised selector? If you post the stack trace, someone may be able to walk you through the things to look for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

many ways, easiest is to set an exception break point.

[image]